# Whole String Content is not getting displayed in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am fetching string from database and forwarding it to a jsp page to display that string . 
content of Sting is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" targetNamespace="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_DataTypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_Internal_DataTypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="RET_MAIL">
        <xsd:annotation>
            **
            <xsd:documentation>Represents the eddbdsbatch request for
                RET_MAIL</xsd:documentation>
            **
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AccountNumber">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="cType">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="CtypeType">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="RET_MAIL" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="RequestId">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                            <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,9}" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingId" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="12" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingRegion" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="S" />
                            <xsd:enumeration value="P" />
                            <xsd:enumeration value="B" />
                            <xsd:enumeration value="A" />
                            <xsd:enumeration value="N" />
                            <xsd:enumeration value="W" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillIndicator" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="LS" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="75" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AccountBalance"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillAmount" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="DateLastchecked"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:pattern
                                value="((0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)dd) ((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="PaymentDueDate"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DateType" />
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ctn">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="ContactNumberType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AlternateCTN" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AltPhoneExtension"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
```

below is the code after fetching this and forwarding it to a jsp.

```
System.out.println(obj.getSchema());
```

here the content is getting displayed as it is.

```
    request.setAttribute("schema", obj.getSchema());
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

in the jsp i have the below code:

```
String schema=(String)request.getAttribute("schema");
if(schema!=null)
{
out.println(schema);
}
else
out.println("no schema found");
```

in jsp the content getting displayed is only  **Represents the eddbdsbatch request for RET_MAIL** which i have highlighted in the content of string above. **I am not getting why the complete content is not getting displayed in jsp.**

Answer (score 1):

Use CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data. Text inside CDATA section will be ignored by the parser. Return the xml content enclosed inside CDATA.

```
<![CDATA[xml content]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is if you look at the HTML source from the browser.

Try putting it in between `<pre>` tags or using HTML/XML escape ("<" -> "<", ">" -> ">" etc).

However, if you meant your XML to be processed by something other than a browser, it is already at the correct format.

Comment: "Try putting it in between <pre> tags "  means in the jsp when i am using out.println?

Comment: yes, assuming you're using HTML output, which would be the default. you didn't show your full jsp so this is just a guess.